# in MySQL I can't set primary key as auto_increment (plus automatically says datatype (11))

Tags: mysql, auto-increment, mysql-workbench

I have a table and its primary key is Measurement_Id I want it to be integer and auto_increment but when I choose Int and click apply it automatically turning to (11) not to int. Just says (11) as datatype and even if auto_increment box is checked after clicking apply auto_increment box turning to unchecked and datatype turning to (11) from INT.

Is it normal ? After clicking apply, It doesnt become auto_increment checked...

Comment: What client software is used? There's no difference between INT and INT(11), btw.

Comment: mysql workbench 5.2 it is ok for int and (11) but why after clicking "apply" auto_increment box turning to unchecked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Docs a regular INT can be any number between -2147483647 and 2147483647, or UNSIGNED form 0 to 4294967295. Notice that's 10 characters unless your using a negative, then you need eleven. Most of the time, SMALLINT or MEDIUMINT will suffice. But, primary keys with auto-increment default to INT(11).

Comment: it is not converting INT to INT(11) it is converting to just (11) so i cant use auto_increment propert or others. is there a bug ?

Comment: so is enough to set as primary key and it will be autoincrement as well?